# How to use gorilla mux with http.TimeoutHandler

Tags: go, middleware, gorilla

In an HTTP server written in go, I use [gorilla/mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) for routing,
I want to use `http.TimeoutHandler` (and/or other "middleware") but I can't understand where I can fit them.

To make it clear:

1. I create a new Router by `gorillaMux := mux.NewRouter()`
2. add my routes by calls like `gorillaMux.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)`
3. I create the server by `server := &http.Server{Addr:":1234"}` and `server.ListenAndServe()`

Where can I insert the `http.TimeoutHandler` or any other middleware for that matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello!")
}

func main() {
    mux := mux.NewRouter()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)

    muxWithMiddlewares := http.TimeoutHandler(mux, time.Second*3, "Timeout!")

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", muxWithMiddlewares)
}
```

If you have more than one HTTP handler, you can stack them up:

```
// this is quite synthetic and ugly example, but it illustrates how Handlers works
muxWithMiddlewares := http.StripPrefix("/api", http.TimeoutHandler(mux, time.Second*3, "Timeout!"))
```

Comment: Note that this applies the timeout on the HTTP request, but the goroutine spun up that is running `rootHandler` does finish afterall even though no one's listening

Comment: How about if there is an transaction in that endpoint ? How we rollback the transaction ?

Answer (score 2):

This solution does not answer the use TimeoutHandler. I posted this here in case anybody wants fine-grain control of their server timeout. This alternative will allow one to define the IdleTimeout and RequestHeaderTimeout if necessary. I am using both gorilla/mux and gorilla/handlers in this example. Hope it helps.

```
// ReadTimeout is a timing constraint on the client http request imposed by the server from the moment
// of initial connection up to the time the entire request body has been read.
// [Accept] --> [TLS Handshake] --> [Request Headers] --> [Request Body] --> [Response]

// WriteTimeout is a time limit imposed on client connecting to the server via http from the
// time the server has completed reading the request header up to the time it has finished writing the response.
// [Accept] --> [TLS Handshake] --> [Request Headers] --> [Request Body] --> [Response]

func main() {
    mux := router.EpicMux()

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler:      handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, mux),
        Addr:         "localhost:8080",
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }

    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}

func EpicMux() http.Handler {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", BaseURLRouter).Methods(http.MethodGet)
    // create the subroutes for v1 and v2
    v1 := r.PathPrefix("api/v1").Subrouter()
    // register handlers to appropriate version
    v1.HandleFunc("/person", PersonHandlerV1).Methods(http.MethodPost)

    v2 := r.PathPrefix("api/v2").Subrouter()
    v2.HandleFunc("/person",    PersonHandlerV2).Methods(http.MethodPost)
    return r
}
```