# How to use timeouthandle with httpRouter

Tags: http, go, middleware

I am having some issues getting timeout to handle safely with   [github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter](http://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter)

I have tried setting the timeout when I initialize the http Server. This does timeout but I get no response back to the user at all.

```
HTTP := &http.Server{
    Addr:    ":" + port,
    Handler: muxWithMiddlewares,
    ReadTimeout:    1 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   1 * time.Second,
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
}
HTTP.ListenAndServe()
```

I have also tried the technique suggested in the below stackoverflow link which explains how to get a timeout working with gorilla mux. This works the very first time a user calls the API, shows a timeout but subsequent requests still funciton as normal. Any help would be much appreciated.

[How to use gorilla mux with http.TimeoutHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659600/how-to-use-gorilla-mux-with-http-timeouthandler)

EDIT: Here is the code I tried first with the solution from the other stackoverflow article. As stated above it works for the first request and shows timeout but each request there after, the request can take however long it needs. Note I was mimicking a slow response by inputting `time.Sleep(5*time.Second)` inside the `handlerA` and `handlerB` here. I would think `timeouthandler` would run If any query takes longer than the time limit but that doesn't appear to be the way I have it configured at the moment in either of the solutions shown here.

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.GET("/xxx/", handlerA)
router.POST("/yyyy/", handlerB)
muxWithMiddlewares := http.TimeoutHandler(router, time.Second*1, "Timeout!")
err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, muxWithMiddlewares)
```

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the solution to that other question correctly? In your code above you're not passing `muxWithMiddlewares` to `ListenAndServe` so if you assigned a timeouthandler to it but did not pass it to `ListenAndServe` then I would not expect it to work, however, if you did I'd be surprised to find it not working.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal thanks for taking a look over. I have copied in the code I tried first based on the stackoverflow link, as stated it does work once but just not on subsequent slow queries.